# Squid3 ncsa basic auth always fails

Tags: 13.04, configuration, proxy, squid

I'm trying to make Squid3 to use basic authentication.
But while i'm providing correct username/password authentication fails!
my ACL and http_access in `squid.conf` is:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/users
auth_param basic realm Private
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow ncsa_users
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
```

I'm creating `/etc/squid3/users` with:

```
htpasswd /etc/squid3/users myusername
```

When I configure the proxy in firefox and it requests password I provide correct username/password but it fails and it prompts again.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Found the problem:**
`htpasswd` uses `-m` (encrypting password with Apache's modified version of MD5)
but Squid's (Squid 3.1.20 on Ubuntu 13.04 repository) `ncsa_auth` uses system's `crypt` function (`unistd.h` or `crypt.h`) to check password (if there be any `crypt()` - I didn't check other scenarios)
So if we run `/usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/users` and check user/password manually we will get:

```
~$ /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/users
user pass
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Solution:**
for creating password file `-d` switch should be used:

```
htpasswd -d /etc/squid3/users myusername
```

(using **-d** tells `htpasswd` to use system's `crypt` function)

Good Luck

Comment: This solution also applies to the latest squid3 version on Debian Wheezy (3.4.8-5~bpo70+1).